# Error: unknown file system

Tags: boot

So I attempted to reinstall ubuntu and ended up coming across grub rescue via USB. I have no cd rom so USB is the only way I can install. Anyhow, I typed in ls and was presented with " hd0 " and " hd1 " neither of which have a file system attached.  I tried anyways and typed in exactly

Ls
Set boot=(hd0)
Set prefix=(hd0)/boot/grub
Insmod normal
Error: unknown file system
Normal
Unknown command 'normal'

Not sure what to do when only two partitions show up.

Comment: Are you getting this when booting from LiveUSB?

Comment: Yes. So I adjusted the boot in bios to load off of USB and if I let it run its course it gives me an error about /dev/disk/by-label/ device did not show up after 30 seconds. And so I would go into boot options ad boot off of usb which brought me to grub rescue.

Comment: There are two options: your computer doesn't boot from USB and tries to boot from HDD, or your LiveUSB is bad. How did you make the LiveUSB?

Comment: Looks like you mis-made your USB somehow. The Ubuntu Desktop install .iso uses a different bootloader, not GRUB.

Comment: Netbootin. Chose the most recent LTS version

Comment: Well I did experience an issue with a corrupted usb drive and had to get more. So would I just need to use a different usb installer?

Comment: How did GRUB (which is not the Ubuntu .iso bootloader) become the USB bootloader? Seems fairly clear that we don't have the full story, so we're not likely to give you useful advice beyond: *Carefully check* that your system is really booting from the USB, and not the HDD (which *does* use GRUB).

Comment: There was a improper configuration on my part that affected my boot. That's what I get for half-a**ing. Apologies for wasting your time guys. I usually try to solve things on my own.